# remove gap when a subview is deleted in scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

In Objective-C, I have a `UIScrollView` in which multiple subviews (created as `xib`) are placed. When I click the delete button of subview I want to delete this particular clicked subview alone and rearrange the scroll view without any gap of the deleted subview..

I have successfully removed the subview using the corresponding tag of subview, but I want to arrange the views in scrollview without the gap

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's a special kind of scroll view called a UITableView that provides this and much more.  UICollectionView is even more general purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you're using auto layout, you'll want to create variable references to your constraints of these subviews. Then when the delete action is performed, update the constraint values to move the other subviews into the correct placement.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to use achieve your goal.

**1. Add UIView in UIScrollView Programmatically.**

Code structure :-

- Add a `view1` on UIScrollView than increase `content size of ScrollView` according to `view1` hight.
- Remove a `view1` from UIScrollView than decrease `content size of ScrollView` according to `view1` hight.

**2. Auto Layout.**

According to me "2" option better approach. You can use prefer tutorial link for how to add a view on scrollview with Auto Layout.  [Using UIScrollView with Auto Layout in iOS](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/)

Comment: Your answer doesn't define any solution regarding to question. You just post auto-layout for scrollview but it there is nothing about how to rearrange the views in scrollview.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy How can i give a accurate answer . He was just asking for suggestion. So i just helping with some references.

Comment: He is specifying scrollview. Leave now give answer for scrollview.